# jest-dom toBeVisible throws: TypeError: element.getRootNode is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jest-dom

We recently updated some of our project dependencies and one of them was `jest-dom`, we went from v5.11.0 to v5.16.4. As of v5.11.10 they introduced a new condition to the `toBeVisible` method so that the element had to be in the document, as part of this check its implementation calls `element.getRootNode`.

Since this change, our tests which use `toBeVisible` now fail with the following message:

```
TypeError: element.getRootNode is not a function
```

I suspect that using `node` as the Jest `testEnvironment` is the issue and that for whatever reason the Node implementation doesn't have `getRootNode` and it probably should.

Is there a way round this (without changing the test environment to `jsdom`, since that causes loads of tests to break)?

Comment: _"the `node` implementation doesn't have `getRootNode` and it probably should"_ - _why_ should it? That's a web API.

Comment: so that you can use `jest-dom` assertions? since the default `testEnvironment` for jest is `node` why would `jest-dom` implement something that doesn't work in both environments?

Comment: `jest-dom` is a third-party library, it's certainly not the case that even the core Jest test environments must support every possible assertion utility. The default test environment doesn't provide _any_ of the web APIs, because it's just Node.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this does make sense, I have raised [this issue](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/458) on their GitHub.